# Intermittent table missing error in SQLite :memory: database

Tags: sqlite, go

We are using SQLite 3.39.4 in Go via github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.16. Connection string is `":memory:?cache=shared&mode=rwc&_mutex=no&_journal=WAL&_sync=NORMAL"`

We occasionally see an error in a test "no such table: Configuration". The confusing thing is, the offending query has been successfully used already in the test case, and the table shows up in a query of sqlite_master afterwards, both in the db connection and the transaction object that raised the error. However, once the error has occurred, the query never succeeds again.

I realise this is a fairly nebulous question but can anyone at least suggest where to look? The database connection has the same pointer value throughout.

**Update**:

On a second try, I could *almost* recreate the problem in this SSCCE:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    os.Remove("example.db")
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, s := range []string{
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists Configuration (" +
            "`id` varchar(1024) NOT NULL," +
            "`body` varchar(10240) DEFAULT NULL, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY (id) " +
            ")",
        "INSERT INTO Configuration (id, body) VALUES ('some-unique-value', 'another-unique-value')",
    } {
        _, err = db.Exec(s)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        tx, err := db.Begin()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        q, err := tx.Prepare("select Configuration.id, Configuration.body \n\t\t\tfrom Configuration\n\t\t\tWHERE Configuration.id = ? ")
        fmt.Println(i, err)
        if q != nil {
            _ = q.Close()
        }

        fmt.Println("tx:")
        showTables(tx)

        fmt.Println("db:")
        showTables(db)

        tx.Commit()
    }
}

func showTables(db interface {
    Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
}) {
    r, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for r.Next() {
        var name string
        _ = r.Scan(&name)
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
}
```

It differs from the actual problem though, in that showTables does not show the table in the SSCCE but does in the real test. This example shows a problem using `:memory:`, but not `example.db`, but only if the transaction is not closed. Is this known or intended behaviour for a memory database?

Comment: SQLite is a single-user database and using `_journal=WAL` doesn't change that. While it does allow multiple connections to use the same database, changes aren't applied directly. They're written to a Write-Ahead-Log and applied later on. Changes in one connection don't block readers from other connections. Those readers will see the *stored* data, not the data in the WAL

Comment: The delay can be significant - as in minutes. I found this the hard way when I wrote a service that synced files by polling S3, writing the data to SQLite and downloading changes in a pipeline. The tool would keep downloading the same files multiple times because updates at the end of the pipeline took longer than the poll interval to appear in the sync step. So the sync step would decide to download the "missing" file again, and again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for such an interesting insight.

Comment: Check the [WAL docs](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). Applying the changes in the WAL is called checkpointing. As the docs say, `By default, SQLite does a checkpoint automatically when the WAL file reaches a threshold size of 1000 pages`. The `Concurrency` section explains how readers see their own changes but not others until checkpointing. A long transaction can *delay* checkpointing

Comment: All this talk about WAL mode is irrelevant to in memory databases, which only support the journal modes `MEMORY` or `OFF`; see [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode)

Comment: Journalling and caching appears to be irrelevant, I get the same results without the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go `database/sql` implicitly uses a connection pool, but `:memory:` databases are by default *private* to the connection that opens them.
See: https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb

Since multiple SQLite connections are being created/closed behind the scenes, you don't really know which connection is running each statement, and against which database, so it's natural that some connections see certain data and others don't.

One way to share connections is to use `cache=shared`, as you tried. But SQLite requires this to be specified as a URI: `file::memory:?cache=shared` (the `file:` is important).

More reliable ways of opening shared memory databases are:

- `file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared` (giving it a name `memdb1`)
- `file:/memdb1?vfs=memdb` (giving it a name `/memdb1`, and using the `memdb` VFS)

Your other parameters are probably unnecessary, maybe harmful (for memory databases).

Comment: Please consider adding [this link](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb) to your answer. Otherwise, thumbs up!